# What does X* x = dynamic_cast<Y*> mean?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

If I have a dynamic cast where the parameter is different to the pointer type being assigned, what does this mean? E.g.:

```
X* x = dynamic_cast<Y*>(something);
```

Here we are casting to `Y*` but the returned pointer is `X*`, so what does this mean?

I am surprised the syntax isn't just:

```
X* x = dynamic_cast(something);
```

because surely wanting to assign to a `X*` would suggest that is the type we would cast-to (or is it??)?

Comment: Maybe `X` is super-class of `Y`.

Comment: The types `X` and `Y` have to be related in some way, for example `X` could be a base class of `Y`.

Comment: Plus `dynamic_cast` will either return a pointer to `Y` or `nullptr` if conversion failed the conversion from `Y` to `X` is taking place implicitly after the `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: This sounds like a cross-cast on a type where `X` is non-virtually inherited multiple times in the same inheritance hierarchy. In pretty much any other case you could either just `static_cast`, or `dynamic_cast` directly to `X`, without the detour through `Y`. Could you provide some additional details on where you found this code, in particular how the types are related and what the inheritance hierarchy looks like?

Comment: @ComicSansMS I didn't see this code anywhere. I was just wondering why the ability exists to have a pointer parameter, when the assignment pointer type would obviously already have a type.

Comment: @mezamorphic Oh, I see. Well, that is simple: The way the C++ language works you need to be able evaluate everything right of the `=` without looking at the left side at all. So in other words: Even though you wrote down the type already, the `dynamic_cast` will not be able to see it if it's left of the `=`. C++11's `auto` helps you getting rid of the redundancy: `auto x = dynamic_cast<X*>(something);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cast;

```
dynamic_cast<Y*>(something);
```

If it succeeds, returns a pointer to `Y`. This is then implicitly cast to `X*` in the assignment.

The code is something equivalent to;

```
Y* y = dynamic_cast<Y*>(something);
X* x = y;
```

There is no information on how `X`, `Y` and `something` are related, but if they are appropriately related, then this all works.

A possible use case of the code `X* x = dynamic_cast<Y*>(something);` is to make sure that `something` is in fact a pointer `Y` before be used via an `X*`. If the `dynamic_cast` fails on the pointers, a null pointer is returned.

[Live sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eef3dc6bf1dd6983) (and see comments)

Comment: But couldnt you just do X* x = dynamic_cast<X*>(something) ?

Comment: @mezamorphic, I would imagine so, yes you could. There may be something else in the code that hints at why this was not originally done; although I can't think of one off hand.

Comment: @mezamorphic Not if `X` is an ambiguous public base of `something`'s actual type, but an unambiguous public base of `Y`. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48b107f52e75fb58).

Comment: The question was on "how does this work", but in general, it's probably a bad idea. Either break the code up into multiple lines to be clear on the intent or comment it well enough to be maintained properly.

Answer (score 1):

> because surely wanting to assign to a X* would suggest that is the
>   type we would cast-to (or is it??)?

There are many contexts in which you might want to use `dynamic_cast` and many of them would be ambiguous. Simply special-casing this one case isn't worth the price.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this is a bad idea. While it can work in instances where X is an ancestor of Y, imagine the case where 'something' is not related to Y, but is related to X. The dynamic_cast(something) would return 0 and assign 0 to x. It would be very easy to miss this subtle issue.

Bottom line: you should always assign a dynamic cast to the same type which you are using as the cast template parameter.